# Bootstrap, dynamically change navigation based on login form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Interesting question and I can't see why its not working.

I have a login form on my navbar wrapped in a span class

```
<span class="loginform">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="signin">Sign in</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
```

I use this when someone clicks on the sign in button (its a prototype right now so no server interaction yet)

```
$('#signin').click(function(){
alert('submitted');
$('#loginform').html('<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="#post">Post Ad</a></li><li><a href="#mine">My Ads</a></li><li><a href="#profile">Ray Bayly</a></li></ul>');
});
```

I added the alert just to ensure it was getting there and working, but for some reason it is not replacing the login form with the new menu items. Is there something different I need to try because its the navbar ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#loginform')

<span class="loginform">
```

'loginform' is the class of the span, not the id. So you need to either change the selector to

```
$('.loginform')
```

Or add an ID of loginform to the span

```
<span class="loginform" id="loginform">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="signin">Sign in</button>
```

`<button type="submit"` always post the form so use `type=button`

Selector is class so use `$('.loginform')`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dhn/10/)

Comment: Thank you all, each one is excellent advice just needed new eyes to see it ,

Answer (score 0):

To properly match the element use a class selector:

```
$('.loginform')
```

instead of an ID selector:

```
$('#loginform')
```

Comment: Fernando, as soon as I saw it , I realized what a rookie mistake it was , thank you very much it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned your selector is wrong. But also you need to stop the form from submitting as this will cause a page refresh and your changes will be lost:

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2XP84/)

```
$('#signin').click(function(e){ /* add "e" */

    e.preventDefault(); /* add this line */

    alert('submitted');
    $('.loginform').html('<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="#post">Post Ad</a></li><li><a href="#mine">My Ads</a></li><li><a href="#profile">Ray Bayly</a></li></ul>');
});
```

If you want this to persist across pages you should do some server side validation on the users login state and serve the correct HTML on page load instead of using javascript.